# Find the Duration in Months between the contents in an Iterator

Tags: java

Code:

```
    Iterator<String> termIncomeKeys = termIncome.keySet().iterator();
    while(termIncomeKeys.hasNext()){
        String month = termIncomeKeys.next();
        System.out.println(month);
    }
```

The month is printed as

Jan(2012) - Jan(2012)

Feb(2012) - Mar(2012)

Apr(2012) - May(2012)

Jun(2012) - Jun(2012)

Jul(2012) - Oct(2012)

What I want to achieve is I want to print the duration in terms of months between each of the entries. That is, Duration between first entry is 1 month, duration between second is 2 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if there is a ready-made class that could parse these strings for you, but the logic is simple:

convert the three-letter months to numbers (e.g. 0-11), and convert the years to numbers as well.
The difference is `<year-diff>*12 + <month-diff>`, where `<month-diff>` might be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Same Year:

```
enum Month{
JAN(0),
FEB(1),
MAR(2),
APR(3),
....
DEC(11);

Month(int index){this.index = index;}
int index;

int getIndex() {return index;}
}

Iterator<String> termIncomeKeys = termIncome.keySet().iterator();
    while(termIncomeKeys.hasNext()){
        String month = termIncomeKeys.next();
        String str[] = month.split("-");
        String m0 = str[0], m1 = str[1];
        String y0 = mo.substr(m0.indexOf('(')+1, mo.lastIndexOf(')'));
        String y1 = m1.substr(m1.indexOf('(')+1, m1.lastIndexOf(')'));
        int yr0 = Integer.parseInt(yo), yr1 = Integer.parseInt(y1);
        m0 = m0.substr(0, mo.indexOf('(')).trim().toUpperCase();
        m1 = m1.substr(0, m1.indexOf('(')).trim(),toUpperCase();
        int duration =  yr1 *Month.valueOf(m1).getIndex() - yr0 *Month.valueOf(m0).getIndex();
    }
```

Comment: Year is not same. Can be different

Comment: Could you please complete the enum Part?

Comment: Thanks. But it prints 0 as the duration between Jan(2012) - Jan(2012). It should be 1.

Comment: Jan(2012) - Jan(2012) is logically zero! You can add 1 to every result.

Comment: Please revert your edit to the previous code. I did manage to solve it by just incrementing duration by 1.